# how to enable disable textbox on radio button click

Tags: html

This is my html

```html
  <input  type="radio" formControlName="customertype" onclick="myfunction()" value="option1" checked/>
 <input type="radio"   formControlName="customertype"  value="option2"/>

 <input type="text"   name="organisationname" disabled="disabled" id="organisationName1" formControlName="organisationname"  class="form-control" placeholder="Orgranisation name" aria-label="First name"/> 

<button type="button"  [disabled]="registrationform.invalid"  class="btn btn-outline-primary buttonspace">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" (click)="resetbtn()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonspace">Reset</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger buttonspace">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input
  type="radio"
  id="setDisabledTrue"
  onclick="if (checked) textbox.disabled = true"
  name="isTextBoxDisabled"
>
<label for="setDisabledTrue">Disabled</label>

<br>

<input
  type="radio"
  id="setDisabledFalse"
  onclick="if (checked) textbox.disabled = false"
  name="isTextBoxDisabled"
>
<label for="setDisabledFalse">Not disabled</label>

<br>
<br>

<input type="text" id="textbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function enable() {
  document.getElementById('text').disabled = false;
}

function disable() {
  document.getElementById('text').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="disable" value="false" onChange="enable()" checked>Enable
<input type="radio"  name="disable" value="true" onChange="disable()">Disable
<br>
<textarea id="text">
</textarea>
```